# Deprecated Warning: Deep requiring like const uuidv5 = require('uuid/v5'); is deprecated as of uuid@7.x in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, node-uuid

how to solve this issue?

(node:2144) DeprecationWarning: Deep requiring like `const uuidv5 = require('uuid/v5');` is deprecated as of uuid@7.x. Please require the top-level module when using the Node.js CommonJS module or use ECMAScript Modules when bundling for the browser. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#deep-requires-now-deprecated for more information.
TypeError: value must be an array of bytes

```
const uuid=require("uuid/v5")

const {product,token}=req.body;
console.log(product)
console.log(product.price)
const idempontencyKey=uuid()
stripe.customers.create({
    email:token.email,
    source:token.id
}).then(customer=>{
    stripe.charges.create({
        amount:10,
        currency:'pkr',
        customer:customer.id,
        receipt_email:token.email,
    },{idempontencyKey})
})
.then(result=>res.status(200).json(result))
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do what the link from the error message tells you to do: https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#deep-requires-now-deprecated

```
const { v5: uuid } = require("uuid")
```